# Where do I set fields that can be edited in Sitecore editor options?

Tags: sitecore, experience-editor

Where in sitecore do I configure what fields are displayed when I click this button?  (Currently, it lists 3 of the 7 fields that are on the template, I'd like to add another to be editable).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGsf1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is one of *Edit Frame* buttons. When you open your control markup, you see something like this:

```
<sc:EditFrame ID="editFrame" runat="server" Buttons="/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Default">
    ...
</sc:EditFrame>
```

It differs for MVC, but is similar. You need to get *Buttons* attribute value.

When you open */sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Edit Frame Buttons/Default* path in *core* database you see list of children. It is your buttons. For your case it should be only one button: *Edit Item*. This item has *Fields* field where using pipe as delimiter is list of fields that are available for editing.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  Googling is hard when you don't know what things are called.